# How to change header text based on URL

Tags: javascript, google-optimize

I'm trying to set up a personalisation through Google optimise which would be live in 4 different countries in where I want to change the header texts. Since it's four different countries it's also in four different languages. I can easily set up four separate experiences but there has to be a way of setting this up just through one experience?

Here's my domain examples:

- https://de.homepage.com/
- https://se.homepage.com/
- https://se.homepage.com/
- https://gb.homepage.com/

I was thinking you could do something like this:

```
If windows.location.currentURL == (https://gb.homepage.com/)

{ display h1 as "GB Header" }

If windows.location.currentURL == (https://nl.homepage.com/)

{ display h1 as "NL Header" }


If windows.location.currentURL == (https://se.homepage.com/)

{ display h1 as "SE Header" }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change h1 based on url with :

```js
if (window.location.hostname === 'gb.homepage.com') {
   document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = 'GB Header'
}
```

Try to do it serverside if possible.